# JDBCTemplate automatically closes connection?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, jdbctemplate

If I use JDBCTemplate, is the connection automatically closed even if i dont use try with resources (or incase I am throwing an exception in a catch block assuming some sqlexception occured) ? Is JDBCTemplate smart enough?

https://www.javatpoint.com/spring-JdbcTemplate-tutorial
This resource says:

> It takes care of creation and release of resources such as creating and closing of connection object etc. So it will not lead to any problem if you forget to close the connection.

So by usnig JDBCTemplate, one can simply forget about connection closing?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can forget about connection closing.

When you have questions about something mentioned in a tutorial, you should always check the **documentation**. You should definitely do that before asking here.

If you had checked the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-JdbcTemplate), you'd have found:

> 3.3.1. Using JdbcTemplate
>
> `JdbcTemplate` is the central class in the JDBC core package. It handles the creation and release of resources, which helps you avoid common errors, such as forgetting to **close the connection**. It performs the basic tasks of the core JDBC workflow (such as statement creation and execution), leaving application code to provide SQL and extract results.

It goes on, of course, so you should really click the link and read it for yourself.

The documentation is well-written, so there is no good excuse not to read it and/or reference it when in doubt.

Comment: Thanks. Will follow this practice.

Comment: Hi, I would also like to see the hikari jdbc database connection getting exhuasted. Any way I can try it out?

Comment: @KushSharma That sounds like an entirely different question, so I suggest you create a new question, if you want this community the answer it.